# Bizarre rejection of edit on case pressure

Tags: discussion, editing

I made a correction to a post [Does liquid cooling mean I no longer need to dust my machine?](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/566201) but it was rejected.

Reject reason A (by Dave Becker): "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

Err, no it doesn't: the intent of the post's owner was to stop foreign material from entering the PC case, as would be achieved with positive pressure inside the case. The post's owner accidentally gave a setup for negative pressure.

Reject reason B (by paradd0x): "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

Of course it is more accurate: the intention of the post owner was to inform the OP how to keep foreign material out of the case, as would be achieved with a positive pressure inside the case. The post's owner accidentally gave a setup for negative pressure.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As the person who posted the answer. I'd have approved this - while the changes were major, it matches what I suggested the question poster *do*

Answer (score 3):

The "reject" reviewers cast that vote almost certainly because your edits changed the meaning of the answer. That is, they would have affected the technical correctness of the post (for better or for worse). Edit reviewers are not expected to judge technical details.

Instead of suggesting an edit, it would have been better to comment. That way, the post owner and other readers can evaluate the correctness of your information.

Comment: Ah well, I just wanted to correct it quietly with no fuss. In the meantime I have commented anyway. I await the rejectors' responses, if they happen upon this post. My edits did not change the meaning of the answer: it was technically correct but erroneous in the implementation details.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - At least one purpose thought your edits did change the meaning of the answer, hence the reason, they selected that reason to reject the edit.  The reviewers are unlikely to know about this question, there is no way to notify them, best to move on to the next edit.