# My question already exists on here (without an answer, yet), so I improved that post instead of posting the question again but the edit was rejected

Tags: support, editing

I have a question, which already exists as a question on here: [xterm copy to PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD independently](https://superuser.com/questions/1279414/xterm-copy-to-primary-and-clipboard-independently) However, unfortunately, there is no answer, yet. So I tried to improve that existing post instead of posting the same question again.

The [suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/765548) was rejected:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I have the exact same issue as the original poster. In which way does may edit deviate from the original intent? Why would one reject the edit if one doesn't take the time to verify if it should really be rejected?

So, what are my options? I don't think I should repost the question anyway?

Comment: Disclosure: I was one of the reject edit votes, in my case because I couldn't verify that you were both referring to the same `Xauthority` file, the change in space, and that you did have exactly the same issue. Though it seemed quite likely, there's been [recent chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44829285#44829285) which has changed the way I handle edit reviews when I cannot verify what is being suggested.

Comment: I have edited this question to include the proposed edit, feel free to roll back :)

Comment: @bertieb Thanks for adding the link to the edit proposal

Comment: @bertieb I'm sorry, I don't get it. Why not skip it, then? And leave it to someone who knows more about this particular topic? Isn't this possible, too? Genuinely curious :-/ A quick search results in nothing but hits for `.Xauthority` by the way - no file called `Xauthority` https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Xauthority

Comment: "we welcome any edits that correct obvious mistakes" from https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6240/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers/6241#6241

Comment: My bad; I meant `Xresources` of course, though what you said about it only being that file no doubt still applies. The proposed edit made also changes to what OP added to that file, which may (or may not) affect the outcome being discussed. It wasn't obvious if what you were doing was a stylistic change, or if it affected the syntax.

Comment: Cf [BenN's answer elsewhere](https://meta.superuser.com/a/11730/461558) and the bit in the A you linked about technical accuracy

Comment: @Jayjayyy Your edits were actually pretty superficial.  I probably wouldn’t have approved the edit.  It being prettier alone, won’t likely make someone with an answer to that question, submit it after nearly 7 months.  Suspect it should be migrated to AskUbuntu to get it in front of the users who might know the answer.  Sadly it’s too old to migrate..

Comment: Reviewers aren't expected to judge the technical accuracy.  You can post technical changes in a comment instead of an edit.  But if you want to include them in an edit, it wouldn't hurt to include an authoritative reference in the edit comment or a post comment.  That still won't guarantee acceptance of a technical change, but it may clarify correction of a technical typo.

Comment: Disclosure: I was *other* one of the reject edit votes, and @bertieb already provided a very thorough summary of what I was thinking, also.  We realize that you had the best of intentions and appreciate your time/effort, but as you can tell by the subsequent comments, it would not have been appropriate to approve that edit.